# What means [x] mean in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -ss 4.5 -t 3.9 -i input.mp4 -vf "fps=18,scale=360:-2:flags=lanczos,palettegen" palette.png

ffmpeg -ss 4.5 -t 3.9 -i input.mp4 -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=18,scale=360:-2:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]palett‎euse" output.gif
```

I used this command to make a gif, but I don't know what `[x];[x][1:v]` means.

What is this all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[x]` is just a name given to the output of the filter.

Please read the [respective documentation entry](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Filtering) and also the part about [link labels](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1).

Usually, a simple filter takes one or more filters and puts them into a filter chain. This is the case in your first command.

You have a *complex* filter in the second command where there can be multiple filter chains combined into a filter graph, as you are processing multiple input streams. The first chain applies `fps` and `scale` to the first input video, and the second chain applies the `paletteuse` filter to the output of the first filterchain and the second input image.

Each filterchain can have zero or more inputs, and zero or more outputs. In a complex filter, you usually have to tell `ffmpeg` what these inputs and outputs are for each of the filter chains. This is what the `[x]` does.

Basically, the `[x]` says, the output of the `fps` and `scale` filter chain is called `x`. Later, it can be re-used as an input for the `paletteuse` filter chain. You don't have to use `x`; you can use any other name as well – something more descriptive would make sense, like `scaled`.

Answer (score 1):

They are link labels.

From the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1),

> The name and arguments of the filter are optionally preceded and
>   followed by a list of link labels. A link label allows one to name a
>   link and associate it to a filter output or input pad.

So, in `scale=360:-2:flags=lanczos[x]`, `x` is the label assigned to the output of the scale filter.

In `[x][1:v]palett‎euse`, `[x]` means to feed paletteuse with the output of the scale filter as the first input and `[1:v]` means to feed the first video stream of the 2nd input (palette.png).